# Google Tag Manager: use "All Custom Events" together with an event condition

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have an event with the following properties:

[image: Custom Event]

Due to reasons (GDPR ‍♂️) we can only fire these events if a custom javascript function (named "Statistic Cookie consent given") returns true.

So, basically I do not know what "All Custom Events" are supposed to catch - is it only custom events with the event name "2checkout event", or simply any event sent in google tag manager?

I want to add that same "catch all" in the conditions. Is the following correct?

[image: Custom Event with condition]

.. or should I only have the "Statistic Cookie consent given" in the "Some Custom Events"-section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"All Custom Events" is confusingly named, but it just means all events with the name `2checkout event`, not all events sent to GTM.

Your second screenshot is very close.  You don't need the `Event` `contains` `2checkout event` under "Some Custom Events" since the `Event name` box is checking that above.  You can just remove that and you should be good!